# Why can't I create environment with python3 on my Ubuntu?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
 python3
Python 3.6.9 (default, Oct  8 2020, 12:12:24) 
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

I want to create an virtual environment but received this error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/types.py", line 171, in <module>
    import functools as _functools
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/functools.py", line 21, in <module>
    from collections import namedtuple
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/collections/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from keyword import iskeyword as _iskeyword
ImportError: cannot import name 'iskeyword'
```

Why is that?

Comment: Do you have any files named `keyword.py`?

Comment: @SuperStormer: Or a directory named `keyword` would work too, thanks to implicit namespace modules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you might have a module that share the same name `keyword` in your local directory. Could you try the below code

```
import keyword
print(dir(keyword))
```

And let me know what it outputs? For me it gave the following

```
['__all__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'iskeyword', 'kwlist']
```

Comment: Yes. I removed a local project called keyword, and the error is gone. But now I got a new issue: Please see my update.